# Update database using variable from csv file in cx_Oracle

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, oracle, cx-oracle

Stuck at a point where I'm getting an error **ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number** when executing the update command in the Oracle database using cx_Oracle & Python3.6.8.

I'm want to use the value of the variable from the CSV file (db_results.csv) and execute the update command.

The db_results.csv file looks like this:

```
id, order_id, product, Courier, state
01, ORD987, Keyboard, DHL, TX
02, ORD976, Charger, Blue Dart, NY
```

My code:

```
con = cx_Oracle.connect("abc/abc@abc")
cur = con.cursor()

with open(r'D:\db_results.csv') as file:
    next(file)
    for line in file:
        x = line.replace('\n', ' ').replace('\r', '')
        columns = x.split(",")
        y = columns[1]
    SQL = "update inventory set model='301547' where order_id = '?'"
    cur.execute(SQL, y)
    con.commit()
con.close()
```

Is there any specific syntax for UPDATE to be used in cx_Oracle? Tried to find examples for this, but none found so far.

Comment: For future readers' reference the cx_Oracle documentation is at http://cx-oracle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html and there are examples at https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/tree/master/samples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- **ORA-01036** raises due to the wrong type of placeholders for oracle, rather prefer using integers prepended with colons such as
  `:1` , `:2`
- Don't forget to trim the second placeholder's value in order to get
  rid of whitespaces wrapping around the value for `y`
- No need to embed the parameters within the DML, rather convert them
  to a tuple such as `(301547, y)`

  ```
  ...
  with open(r'D:\db_results.csv') as file:
      next(file)
      for line in file:
          x = line.replace('\n', ' ').replace('\r', '')
          columns = x.split(",")
          y = columns[1]
          SQL = "UPDATE inventory SET model=:1 WHERE order_id = TRIM(:2)"
          cur.execute(SQL, (301657, y))
      con.commit()
  con.close()
  ```

Comment: Hi Barbaros, I tried with the following code and got an error.

cur.executemany(SQL, (301547, y))
**TypeError: parameters should be a list of sequences/dictionaries or an integer specifying the number of times to execute the statement**

Comment: excuse me @GauravMarothia , I left **many** there by mistake, retry as edited please.

Comment: It worked... Thank you so much @Barbaros Özhan

Comment: Hi Barbaros, the code runs without any error but the value is still not updated in the database. Could you please help?

Comment: @GauravMarothia Do you add `con.commit()` after the DML as in your original code ? And are you sure that the matching `order_id` values exist within the table?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229356/discussion-between-gaurav-marothia-and-barbaros-ozhan).

Answer (score 0):

Calling `cur.execute()` once for each CSV line (as shown in the accepted answer) will be really slow and cannot be recommended.

Instead, look at using `cur.executemany()`, similar to the code in the cx_Oracle documentation [Loading CSV Files into Oracle Database](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/batch_statement.html#loading-csv-files-into-oracle-database):

```
with open('testsp.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    sql = "insert into test (id,name) values (:1, :2)"
    data = []
    for line in csv_reader:
        data.append((line[0], line[1]))
        if len(data) % batch_size == 0:
            cursor.executemany(sql, data)
            data = []
    if data:
        cursor.executemany(sql, data)
    con.commit()
```

In your case the SQL would be the UPDATE statement, and you just need to construct the `data` variable with your desired values.